# Converting pug to handlebars

Tags: javascript, pug

There used to be a useful library jade-to-handlebars in npm.  With jade being renamed to pug, is there a conversion from pug files to handlebars?  Or pug to jade so I can use jade-to-handlebars

Comment: Have you tried just using `jade-to-handlebars`? I don't know how many changes there have been since the rename, but if they're haven't been to many, I'd assume just using old tools for jade should still work.

Comment: I did, however, I believe due to file extensions names it is broken (well, isn't compatible - I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

[pug-to-handlebars](https://github.com/nachoverdon/pug-to-handlebars)

Comment: Not exactly sure. I feel like I saw that library, and it was throwing errors due to file extensions.  Looks like it finally got changed.  I could be wrong.  Regardless, I moved on or figured it out.  Thanks though, I'll give you some up votes for answering a year old question lol

Comment: I just tried that library to convert a .pug file to .hbs, first it wasn't possible to install it from the npm registry (path error / 404), I had to resort to "npm install -g git+https://github.com/nachoverdon/pug-to-handlebars.git" and then: nothing happend. No conversion, no file, no error, just silence, no matter which options I tried. So I guess this library is useless

Comment: Just for completion and some readers in 2017: I simply renamed the .pug file to .jade, and used the old jade-to-handlebars library, which produced the desired output.